# Are there companies or gov jobs that pay for your master's or PhD full time if you cut a deal with them?

Tags: student, reimbursement, masters

I am looking to do a Master's in Computer Engineering and possibly a PhD in Computer Engineering full-time and I would like to find a company (or US Government job) that would pay for it.  I would be willing to "cut a deal" with them, something like upon graduation, I would have to stay with this company for X years.  So they do the favor of paying for my tuition, and I do the favor of providing them service for X years.

Is this possible? If so, where? And how do I ask this question in a professional manner in a job interview setting?

Comment: I haven't considered military seriously, but if all other options fail then I would.

Comment: A PhD you should not have tuition.  Often the military will offer a masters.   I was offered a masters and serve 4 years (as an officer).

Comment: @Paparazzi - are you suggesting the military is the only option here?

Comment: Have you considered just getting a related job and doing your Master's part time? I imagine there are way more companies willing to pay for the studies of their employee than those who are willing to pay in advance, and you'd likely also be looking at a shorter time commitment.

Comment: Yes there are government agencies that do this. I could have done it with the agency I worked for DOD (as a civilian not military). The catch is yes you are making a commitment and you have to study what they need studied not what you want to study.  So if your needs and their coincide, then you may be able to work a deal.

Comment: However, and it is a big however, they must really need an expert at the PhD level and not be able to hire one because you will be going to school instead of working. You probably have to work there for several years as well and be an outstanding performer before they will consider it too. And you have to have a manager who is willing to look towards the needs of the whole organization and not just his small part because likely he will not be able to hire a replacement for you while you go to school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

There is a [Tax Form](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/payroll/benefits-allowances/scholarships-bursaries-tuition-training.html) thus there's probably a reason for such a form.

Here's a [list of companies](https://www.scholarships.com/financial-aid/college-scholarships/scholarships-by-type/corporate-scholarships/) that pay between $1000 and $100K. In addition to asking the employer for bonuses or reimbursement you can ask the school about other means to obtain money.

Read "[What are scholarships, grants and bursaries?](http://www.newyouth.ca/school/pay-school/what-are-scholarships-grants-and-bursaries)".

Scholarships are money awards you get for your academic performance (high grades) or other achievements. Grants are money awards you get based on high grades or financial need. You can also receive a grant when you carry out academic research projects. Bursaries are money awards you get based on your financial needs.

You can ask during the interview but paying for a PhD is likely to be seen as an unexpected and expensive request; expect it to affect bonuses and pay. The chances of them paying, you going to school, and then you returning would be a gamble for the company.

I know people who have asked people with whom they are acquainted and own a business if they paid for a course that the business owner suggested would they then hire them for the position if they came back with great Marks. The business owner had lots of money and little to lose, despite that they declined.